# Adding links to photo slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, tooltip, photo

I am having a problem with my code. I know next to nothing about JavaScript, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to make the banners and photos in this fading slider (only three pictures, but different links for each) link to a page on the website. I can't figure out how to do this.

Here's a link to the website so you can see what I'm trying to do,
http://www.buildings4babies.org

Here is my current script.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.aToolTip = function(options) {

        // setup default settings
        var defaults = {
            clickIt: true,
            closeTipBtn: 'aToolTipCloseBtn',
            fixed: false,
            inSpeed: 200,
            outSpeed: 0,
            tipContent: '',
            toolTipClass: 'aToolTip',
            xOffset: 5,
            yOffset: 5
        },

        // This makes it so the users custom options overrides the default ones
        settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            // Decide weather to use a title attr as the tooltip content
            if(obj.attr('title')){
                // set the tooltip content/text to be the obj title attribute
                var tipContent = obj.attr('title');  
            } else {
                // if no title attribute set it to the tipContent option in settings
                var tipContent = settings.tipContent;
            }

            // check if obj has a title attribute and if click feature is off
            if(tipContent && !settings.clickIt){    
                // Activate on hover    
                obj.hover(function(el){
                    obj.attr({title: ''});                        
                    $('body').append("<div class='"+ settings.toolTipClass +"'><p class='aToolTipContent'>"+ tipContent +"</p></div>");
                    $('.' + settings.toolTipClass).css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        display: 'none',
                        zIndex: '50000',
                        top: (obj.offset().top - $('.' + settings.toolTipClass).outerHeight() - settings.yOffset) + 'px',
                        left: (obj.offset().left + 1/2*(obj.outerWidth()) + settings.xOffset) + 'px'
                    })
                    .stop().fadeIn(settings.inSpeed);   
                },
                function(){ 
                    // Fade out
                    $('.' + settings.toolTipClass).stop().fadeOut(settings.outSpeed, function(){$(this).remove();});
                }); 
            }

            // Follow mouse if fixed is false and click is false
            if(!settings.fixed && !settings.clickIt){
                obj.mousemove(function(el){
                    $('.' + settings.toolTipClass).css({
                        top: (el.pageY - $('.' + settings.toolTipClass).outerHeight() - settings.yOffset),
                        left: (el.pageX + settings.xOffset)
                    })
                });         
            }           

            // check if click feature is enabled
            if(tipContent && settings.clickIt){
                // Activate on click    
                obj.click(function(el){
                    obj.attr({title: ''});                        
                    $('body').append("<div class='"+ settings.toolTipClass +"'><p class='aToolTipContent'>"+ tipContent +"</p></div>");
                    $('.' + settings.toolTipClass).append("<a class='"+ settings.closeTipBtn +"' href='#' alt='close'>close</a>");
                    $('.' + settings.toolTipClass).css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        display: 'none',
                        zIndex: '50000',
                        top: (obj.offset().top - $('.' + settings.toolTipClass).outerHeight() - settings.yOffset) + 'px',
                        left: (obj.offset().left + obj.outerWidth() + settings.xOffset) + 'px'
                    })
                    .fadeIn(settings.inSpeed);  
                    // Click to close tooltip
                    $('.' + settings.closeTipBtn).click(function(){
                        $('.' + settings.toolTipClass).fadeOut(settings.outSpeed, function(){$(this).remove();});
                        return false;
                    });      
                    return false;           
                });
            }

        }); // END: return this

        // returns the jQuery object to allow for chainability.  
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That's a pretty hefty library for knowing "next to nothing" :)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to point you to jQuery methods since you are already using it.

You need to find out the element id of the pictures that you want to use as a linking element. In html, it should look like this: `"id="asdfasdf"`.

Unfortunately, I could not find the point in your script where pictures are inserted. I don't think you are looking in the right place, honestly, this function seems to display [tooltips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip) only.

Anyway, once you found the id of your element you can select it using jQuery's `$('#idofyourelement')`.  If they don't have an id, you can select them otherwise. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/) for an introduction.

Once you selected your element, you can use the [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) -method to add an html link around it ***or*** you can install a [click - listner](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and and call a function that opens a new link:

```
function goToLink() {
      window.location = "http://www.whereveryouwant.com"
    }

$("#idofyourpicture").click(goToLink);
```

Do this for every picture you want to use as a link.